# how to export a class in react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

i am trying to connect firebase to my expo application, but it does not appear to be able to read the function in my firebase class. Any ideas?

```
import Fire from "./Fire";
export default class App extends React.Component {

componentDidMount() {
        var firebase = new Fire((error, user) => {
            if (error) {
                return alert("uh, oh, something went wrong");
            }

componentWillUnmount() {
        firebase.detach();
    }
}
```

//other class (firebase)

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import "@firebase/firestore";

class Fire {


firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                callback(null, user);
            } else {
                firebase
                    .auth()
                    .signInAnonymously()
                    .catch((error) => {
                        callback(error);
                    }); // 3:18
            }
        });
    }

detach() {
        this.unsubscribe();
    }
}


export default { Fire };
```

the error I get from expo

[image]

Comment: You're trying to call `new Fire` and pass a closure with `error, user` as parameters, but that doesn't seem to be defined on your `class Fire`. Also, the `export default` should be *outside* the class definition.

Comment: Sorry did the edit again, the export is outside the class definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you export Fire class like this:

```
export class Fire {...}
```

and remove the `export default` statement,
and import Fire using this statement:

```
import {Fire} from './Fire'
```

your problem is sloved.

Or a simple way is removing curly braces around Fire in export statement:

```
export default Fire
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be importing Fire incorrectly.

In you app.js file

Change `import Fire from "./Fire";` to `import { Fire } from "./Fire";`

The difference being the curly braces around the Fire import.
This might solve your problem and allow app.js to recognize your Fire class.